# Identify audio plug

Tags: identification, plug

I got an old Siemens RW666 LP player, but the cable is a little short... What plug is this, so I can get an extension cord?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a 180 degree  5 pin DIN they were fairly common a few decades ago.  less so recently.

180 degree describes the angle populated with pins

Comment: nice... So quick! as I looked up parts listings I found it is also branded "5pin DIN MIDI" or "5Pin DIN Audio MIDI AT", befitting the audio-source it carries.

Comment: MIDI is Musical Instrument Digital Interface - it uses that plug as did IBM PC keyboards (prior to the PS/2)

Answer (score 0):

It is a DIN connector for analog audio signals, that were initially standardized by Deutsches Institut fur Normung (DIN) . Some of these connectors have also been used in analog video applications and digital interfaces.

look at [here](http://pinouts.ru/Home/DinAudio_pinout.shtml) for more info